# OpsWorks: Bundle install behind a firewall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, aws-opsworks

I am trying to run an environment behind a firewall on OpsWorks.
My app instances are in a private subnet in a VPC and I noticed I cannot run bundle install (because I don't have access to rubygems from my instance.)

What is the best way to go around it?

I was thinking that I could run bundle install locally and check in the gems inside the repo but I am not sure how to do that.

Before Opsworks I was using capistrano (there is a strategy called copy_bundled: https://github.com/rudionrails/capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `bundle install --deployment` - this will store all bundled gems in your vendor/ directory, which can then be stored in your version control. There are some downsides (size of your VCS repo being the primary problem) but has the benefit of ensuring a repeatable environment for your production code.

Note that on your production system, all command line actions involving ruby / rake / rails will require the `bundle exec ...` prefix because ruby will no longer know where to find gems otherwise.